# Iterating over a dictionary while iterating a dictionary list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am writing a program and need to use this function to add Dependencies to an xml file. This code works, but I would like to ask if there is a more pythonic way to do so.

The part I believe I am doing in a non-pythonic way is the nested for loop. Is there a better way to iterate a list of dictionaries and each value?

```
def add_Dependencies(self):
        """ Adds the dependencies in a feature using dictionaries. When
            a feature is loaded, its dependencies are added to 
            dictionaries. Three for each type of software that the 
            dependencies are categorized as."""

        dependency_dict_list = [
            self.os_dict, self.visual_dict, self.audio_dict
            ]   

        dependencies = self.dependencies
        for dictionary in dependency_dict_list:                                                
            for feature, software in dictionary.items():                                            
                if all(dependency.text != feature for dependency in dependencies):
                    etree.SubElement(dependencies,"Dependency", Software = software).text = feature
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing unpythonic about nested for-loops. Your code can be refactored to use comprehensions if you want, but since the innermost statement is side-effectful, and not intended to return a value, it wouldn't be wise to e.g. wrap it in a lambda or something just so it can occur in a comprehension. I believe your method with loops is clean, good, easy-to-read code and it's probably not a great use of time to harp on making it so-called "pythonic".

Comment: Is `self.dependencies` going to be empty before this function is called? It seems like you'd have much faster code if you merged the multiple dictionaries together first (using a data structure with O(1) key lookups) and only created the XML elements afterwards.

Comment: @Blckknght self.dependencies will be an lxml object (should have specified that.) dependency in dependencies are the children. I will look into that.

Comment: @Mr.F Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Mr.F I am glad to hear from a more experienced python user that list comprehension-all-the-things is not always the most pythonic way. Personally 9 out of 10 examples I still find it more clear and easy to understand more verbose code without them.

Comment: @OscarReyes: My point is: do you expect there to already be children to the XML object when the function is first called? Will it ever be called more than once? Because your `all` call checking each child for the current `feature` is probably going to be fairly slow.

Comment: @Blckknght It could be empty or have children the first time it is called, depending if an existing file was loaded, and the user is editing a "feature" that has one or more "Dependency" in "Dependencies".  

edit: This function is called multiple times if the user is adding multiple dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, nothing wrong with that at all. I put this together if you'd be interested it should be a little faster and is a tad less verbose. I cut out the nested for loop and flipped the all to an any (it reads a little cleaner to me, but that's really just taste).

```
all_dependencies = dict(self.os_dist, **self.visual_dict)
all_dependencies.update(self.audio_dict)

for feature, software in dictionary.items():
    if not any(dependency.text == feature for dependency in dependencies):
        etree.SubElement(dependencies,"Dependency", Software = software).text = feature
```

Comment: Could you explain how the first line works? If it would not be much trouble. When trying to do something like it on IDLE to see how it works, I get an error message.

Comment: `dict.update()` returns `None`, so your `all_dependencies` will be `None`.

Comment: I see you changed the code, but python shell says dict expects at most 1 argument.

Comment: I had made a typo while using my phone but just fixed it. It should work now by concat 2 dictionaries into a single (it's the fastest way I know to combine 2 dictionaries and is a lot faster for iterating large dicts) with the 2nd one as a kwarg

Comment: This also helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.ChainMap` to merge your three dictionaries into a single dictionary-like mapping. Or, since you don't care about the values, you could merge their keys into a `set`

It's not very important to use this to avoid the nested loops. Nested loops can be perfectly Pythonic, though you might want to factor some inner bits out into functions if the nesting gets too deep.

The real reason you might want to use a `ChainMap` or `set` here is to avoid the `O(N**2)` runtime complexity of searching your XML tree to eliminate duplicate dependencies. That they also eliminate a level of nesting is a minor side benefit.

Try something like this:

```
new_dependencies = (set(self.os_dict).union(self.visual_dict, self.audio_dict) -
                    set(dependency.text for dependency in self.dependencies))

for feature in new_dependencies:
   etree.SubElement(self.dependencies,"Dependency", Software = software).text = feature
```